# HowTo: iOS MapKit animated image marker / annotation

Tags: animation, swift3, mapkit, sequence, mkannotation

I have sequence of images that i want to use as animation, and i want to apply this animation to specific annotation.

How do I change MapKit default Annotation image and how to make it animated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make *custom image* or *animated image* marker annotation:

- In resources: add desired animation X sequence images: frame_1.png to frame_X.png
- In code: extend your View Controller  with MKMapViewDelegte like this:

`class MyViewController: MKMapViewDelegate`

In storyboard:

1. Pick your MapKit view
2. Go to Utilities frame and choose
   Connections Inspector
3. Connect delegate element with your
   controller.

Now your view controller could get callbacks from MapView.

In code: 
Add following code to override marker/annotation setup callback

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
    {
        if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "test"

        anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if anView == nil {
            anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            anView!.image = UIImage(named:"frame_1")
            anView!.canShowCallout = true


           Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.05, target: self, selector: #selector(Changeimage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        }
        else {
            anView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        return anView
    }

    func Changeimage()
    {
        if count == 8
        {
            count=0
        }
        else
        {
            anView!.image = UIImage(named:"frame_\(count+1)")
            anView!.canShowCallout = true
            count=count+1
        }
    }
```

If you don't need animation, just remove Timer line from the code.